# Runnig JSUnit tests without a test suite

Tags: jsunit

Is there a way to run JSUnit tests without specifying test suite file.
I want to run all the tests in a particular package so that one does not have to remember to add any new test to the existing suite.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both Eclipse and Maven will do this for you.